# how to category/subcategory/city/firm-name url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, seo, permalink-fu

i am using ruby on rails
i have models 
-category
-subcategory
-city
-firm

when i click on category it will show sub categories and permalink should be:  example.com/category
when i click subcategory it will show firms and city names. example.com/category/subcategory
when i click on city name it will filter firms belongs to that city example.com/category/subcategory/city
when i click on firm name it will show example.com/category/subcategory/city/firm-name

firms may have more than one sub category

i used premalink_fu but i could not do that sub category system.
category,subcategory,city,firm tables have their own permalink field on db. 
but i don't know how to combine them dynamically.

i can do example.com/category but i cant do example.com/category/subcategory

how can i do that please help me

Answer (score 0):

I stored permalinks at mysql via permalink_fu plugin and then call as parameter for action show:

city show.rhtml

```
<%= link_to s.isim, {:controller => 'sehir', :action => 'goster', :kategori=>@kategori.permalink ,:altkategori=>@altkategori.permalink, :permalink=>s.permalink} -%> -
```

route.rb

```
map.sehirs '/:kategori/:altkategori/:permalink', :controller => 'sehir', :action=>'goster'
```